# Visualforce Email Template - Related To

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am trying to fetch all the Opportunities associated with the User.Below is the Visualforce Email Template. I am stuck with the line of the code

> received
>   error:    Error: Invalid field Opportunities__r for SObject User

```
<messaging:emailTemplate  recipientType="User" relatedToType="User" subject="Opportunity report for User: {!relatedTo.Name}"
   language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<html>
<body>
    <p> Dear {!recipient.Name},</p>
    <p>Below is the list of opportunities . </p>
    <p>table border = "0" </p>

    <p> Close Date</p> <p>Opportunity Name</p>
    <th>Amount</th> <th>Stage</th>
    </tr>
   <apex:repeat var="Opp" value="{!relatedTo.Opportunities__r}"> 
    <apex:OutputPanel rendered = "{!Opp.MightyHR__Closein7days__c = 1}" >  
    <tr>
    <td><a  href =" https://gopagoni-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/{!Opp.Id}">{!Opp.CloseDate}</a></td>
    <td>{!Opp.Name}</td>
    <td> {!Opp.Amount}</td>
    <td>{!Opp.Stage}</td>
    </tr>
    </apex:OutputPanel>

     </apex:repeat>


    </table>
    <p/>
    <center>
    <apex:outputLink value="http://www.salesforce.com">
     For more detailed information login to Salesforce.com
                </apex:outputLink>

     </center>

    </body>

</html>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: you can't access `relatedTo.Opportunities__r` related records. you may require controller help here. Try like this.. http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/05/visualforce-email-template-with-custom.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. If we observe the Schema from User to Opportunity there is reference but when comes to the visual email template it doesn't work.Any clue y  this happens @Ratan

Comment: In case of VF email template reference field won't work like trigger context.. We can say it is a salesforce limitations.. Yeah there is a very good reason for this limitation. I think because of performance issue or something I am not sure.. Hope someone will give you a correct Ans to question.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process flow how i achieved this.
Refer to the http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/05/visualforce-email-template-with-custom.html .

The above links helps to write the code.

1.Created an Apex class
2.Visualforce controller
3.Visualforce email template.
 In the Template we pass the User id.this will be passed to the controller and then to the apex class.The apex class fetches the records and displays to the user